# JavaFX 8 How to do a lambda expression with zero parameters

Tags: java, lambda, closures, javafx-8

I am still totally confused about Java lambdas/lambda syntax. I read that lambdas take two general forms:

```
(param1, param2, ...) -> expression;

(param1, param2, ...) -> { /* code statements */ };
```

OK, fine. And that when the expression doesn't accept parameters (and is said to be empty), the parentheses are still required.

Now, the following code works correctly:

```
primaryStage.show();
PauseTransition pause =
    new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
pause.setOnFinished(event ->
    primaryStage.hide());
pause.play();
```

But, when I think to myself that `primaryStage.hide()` does not require any parameter, I think I can remove the parameter from the lambda expression. This (obeying the rule to keep brackets) gives me the following code:

```
primaryStage.show();
PauseTransition pause =
    new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
pause.setOnFinished(() ->
    primaryStage.hide());
pause.play();
```

Which doesn't work!!!

I've tried many permutations, to no avail. Despite poring over pages and pages about lambdas I still cant quite get it straight in my head.

I am really struggling with lambdas. Could someone please give me a clear explanation of what is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.setOnFinished()` method takes an `EventHandler` as an argument (which is a functional interface).

It has one method named [handle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html#handle-T-) that takes in a generic type, this is the method whose parameters you should be considering; So you must pass in a parameter to it.

Comment: OH!!! Grrr, thats so obvious! I couldnt see the wood for the trees.
We're calling `.setOnFinished()`!!! And passing it a lambda. I feel really stupid for asking now!

Comment: The lambdas could be a bit confusing. But once you get the hang of them, they will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If the method your lambda is implementing has a parameter, you must have one in your argument list *even if you don't use it.*  You indicated that `event -> primaryStage.hide()` worked, so you must be implementing a method with a parameter.

This is just like if you were actually implementing that interface with an anonymous class:

```
new Consumer<Event>() {
  @Override public void accept(Event event) { // can't omit the argument!
    primaryStage.hide(); // doesn't use the argument
  }
}
```